# Open attachements in PDF from mobile

Tags: android, ios, pdf, windows-phone, attachment

I created a PDF with some files attached and links (in fact annotations) to these files:
[image: PDF attachments]

When I open the PDF from my computer with Acrobat Reader I'm able to open all files either by clicking directly on the "Attachments" column or clicking on the links (annotations).

But when I try to do the same on mobile (iOS, Android or WP) via Acrobat Reader application (I also tried with Foxit App and few others) it doesn't work:

- I can't access to the attachments column
- When I clicked on the links (annotations) nothing happen

So, I want to know if someone know a mobile application (no matter of the OS) that is able to open/access to the attachments in a PDF ?

Thank you.

Gerald.

Answer (score 0):

File attachments and other annotations are beyond the scope of most (if not any) mobile PDF viewer. You might have to look around to find a viewer which offers to support these objects; maybe you are lucky.

PDF viewers for mobile devices do evolve quite rapidly, so, things may change within the next few months…

Comment: Thank you Max, I suspected this answer. I will try to post this issue on the Adobe forum and see what happen.

Comment: Another "good idea" would be to directly address the leading makers of PDF viewers for mobile devices to consider supporting annotations and attachments.